# Windows Security freezes my computer when accessing Chrome's password manager. Can I speed it up or disable it?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, password-management

I use Chrome as my default browser in Windows 10. Google Chrome manages my passwords for websites that I need to log into. Whenever I try to access a password from my Saved Passwords in Chrome, a Windows Security box pops up asking for my Windows password. See picture below.

[image]

This would be fine, except this pop-up suddenly freezes my computer for about 1-2 minutes! This is quite frustrating. It appears that this is not an uncommon problem. See [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/13412329?hl=en) for example. The solution posted there, however, did not fix my problem. Accessing my saved passwords on Chrome is still ludicrously slow.

**Does anyone know of another possible fix to speed this up?**

**Alternatively, is there a way to disable Windows Security from guarding my saved passwords on Chrome?** I've found others having a similar problem. The suggested solution usually seems to be to `chrome://flags` and disable `Password Manager Re-authentication` (see e.g. [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/google-chrome-ask-for-windows-10-password-to-view/4a79577b-1f92-42e3-95f1-b1b5bac0da6e)).  The problem is, Password Manager Re-authentication isn't on the list!

Comment: I suppose using a different password manager is out of the question?

Comment: From google chrome community, it seems there is no way to turn this security feature off. In order to protect your saved passwords, you have to enter your Windows password.

Comment: Ok, after some more searching, I see that it can't be disabled. But why is it soooo slooow?!?

Comment: And if I used a different password manager, it seems that Windows Security would still prompt me for my Windows password. And I'd still have the problem of my computer freezing up for a few minutes every time I want to view a saved password. I'll at least give that a try...

Answer (score -2):

WHY this prompt is happening: Chrome is likely deliberately triggering that UAC (User Authentication Control) security prompt. Either that or its storing in the recommended secure location in Windows & accessing it SHOULD cause that prompt. Imagine walking away from your desk for a moment & your coworker accessed all your passwords. Consider this a prompt 'are you really Mark?'

I sadly have no guidance for making the process quicker as its running some complex security magic. Wiping Windows fresh, a newer PC, SSD, or more RAM may help, but that's likely not the answer you want.

You CAN turn off UAC: type `uac` in Windows-menu/search (alternatively Control Panel, System and Security, Change User Account Control settings), slide the dial down. However this REALLY does reduce the security of your PC. Consider the trade-off's carefully...

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/topic/guided-help-adjust-user-account-control-settings-in-windows-7-and-windows-8-605f891d-42c5-2b93-4b4b-e4c5d4d35f60
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/the-basics-of-uac/ba-p/372313
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works